# Getting contacts gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-contacts

I want to get all the contacts from the phone and display it in a list>for that i have written a code which works fine.But some times i get null pointer exception,due to which my app crashes.I don't know whats the problem as some times it works perfectly but sometimes it gives null pointer exception.

Code

```
public static JSONArray getAllContactList(Context context) {
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        alAllContacts = new ArrayList<ContactModel>();

        while (!(c == null) && c.moveToNext()) {
            String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (number.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
//                    Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
//                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = '" + id + "'", null, null);

                Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);


                while (phones.moveToNext() && phones != null) {

                    String contactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    contactNumber = contactNumber.replace("+", "");

                    if (contactNumber.length() > 10) {
                        contactNumber = contactNumber.substring(2);
                    }
//                    contactNumber.replace("+91", "");
                    alAllContacts.add(new ContactModel(contactName, contactNumber));

//
                }

            }


            jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < alAllContacts.size(); i++) {
                jsonArray.put(alAllContacts.get(i).getJSONObject());
            }

        }
        c.close();


        return jsonArray;

    }
```

If am getting Null pointer then the logcat shows it is at this line

```
Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);


                    while (phones.moveToNext() && phones != null) {
```

LOGCAT

```
E/CursorLeakDetecter﹕ PossibleCursorLeak:content://com.android.contacts/data/phones,QueryCounter:5
    android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:399)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.CommonFunctions.CommonFunctions.getAllContactList(CommonFunctions.java:68)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.Group.ContactListFragment$getContactsyncedContacts.doInBackground(ContactListFragment.java:250)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.Group.ContactListFragment$getContactsyncedContacts.doInBackground(ContactListFragment.java:246)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
09-05 13:31:03.774  28948-28977/example.com.pocketdocs E/CursorLeakDetecter﹕ PossibleCursorLeak:content://com.android.contacts/data/phones,QueryCounter:6
    android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:399)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.CommonFunctions.CommonFunctions.getAllContactList(CommonFunctions.java:68)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.Group.ContactListFragment$getContactsyncedContacts.doInBackground(ContactListFragment.java:250)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.Group.ContactListFragment$getContactsyncedContacts.doInBackground(ContactListFragment.java:246)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: Did you debug what's null?

Comment: I cannot get it cos some times the code works but some times it dont

Comment: Please get the error from the Logcat. We can't help with just the code (maybe use a monkey ?)

Comment: I have updated my post,please do have a look\

Answer (score 0):

You missed single quote(because id is string),So change

```
Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
```

to

```
Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " ='" + id + "'", null, null);
```